# Webpack is including a UTF charcter "φ" into the bundle which breaks my JSP page?

Tags: java, reactjs, jsp, tomcat, webpack

I'm trying to import a react component what was bundled using webpack and a babel transform plugin.  It works fine in my Storybook setup, but when I pull that bundle into my JSP page running in Tomcat, it won't render.

Tomcat is complaining of illegal character. When I open up web pack I see this character "φ".

What is this and how do I fix it?

Here's what the JSP page looks like

```
<%@ include file="../core/include/MainInclude.jsp"%>
<%@ include file="../core/include/header.jsp"%>
<%@ include file="../core/include/NavBarTopReact.jsp"%>

<section class="container container-fluid">
    <%@ include file="../core/include/Banner.jsp"%>
    <%@ include file="../core/include/PageTitleHeader.jsp"%>
    <%--INSERT Page Content Here--%>

    <div id="topDiv"></div>

    <script>

        var connect = {
            api: 'https://mine51.topcat.dev.net',
            auth: 'Basic ' + btoa('xxxxxx:yyyyyyyy'),,
            oDataString: '',
        };

        var header = new PfsTopNav('topDiv',connect);

    </script>
</section>
```

Comment: Why is tomcat even compaining about a character in a .js file? What is the source code of the JSP, and the exact and complete error message you get?

Comment: I'm sorry, it's the browser that is complaining. I meant to say that the js file is running or rather pulled into the the JSP file. The message is basically 'illegal character at line 61319' and then I open up the js file I see this character buried in there. φ

Comment: What is the source code of the JSP?

Comment: Source? Your mean what’s serving the JSP? Or what it’s written in?

Comment: The source code that is inside the JSP file that loads the JS script. What's service the JSP is tomcat. I don't want the source of Tomcat. I want the source code of the JSP served by Tomcat.

Comment: I see. It's just some JSP tags, with some HTML mixed in. The JSP uses Bootstrap for layout and CSS, and that is pulled in along with a bunch of other JSP include files. After that it pulls in some js libraires such as JQuery. Would it be help if I posted the JSP file?